# set up a list of neighboring cell in fortran

Tags: linked-list, fortran, fortran90

I want to make a **linked-list** in **fortran90** to compute the **potential** of N-particle system.
I used below code for **2D** and it worked:

```
    do iy=1,my
    do ix=1,mx
      imap=(icell(ix,iy)-1)*8
      map(imap+ 1)=icell(ix+1,iy  )
      map(imap+ 2)=icell(ix+1,iy+1)
      map(imap+ 3)=icell(ix  ,iy+1)
      map(imap+ 4)=icell(ix-1,iy+1)
      map(imap+ 5)=icell(ix-1,iy  )
      map(imap+ 6)=icell(ix-1,iy-1)
      map(imap+ 7)=icell(ix  ,iy-1)
      map(imap+ 8)=icell(ix+1,iy-1)
    enddo
  enddo
```

But when I want to modify this for **3D** simulation, I have big problem with potential growing!!

```
icell(ix,iy,iz)=1+mod(ix-1+mcell_x,mcell_x)+mod(iy-1+mcell_y,mcell_y)*mcell_x+mod(iz-1+mcell_z,mcell_z)*mcell_x*mcell_y
do iz=1,mcell_z
  do iy=1,mcell_y
do ix=1,mcell_x
  imap=(icell(ix,iy,iz)-1)*26
  map(imap+1 )=icell(ix+1,iy  ,iz  )
  map(imap+2 )=icell(ix+1,iy+1,iz  )
  map(imap+3 )=icell(ix  ,iy+1,iz  )
  map(imap+4 )=icell(ix-1,iy+1,iz  )
  map(imap+5 )=icell(ix-1,iy  ,iz  )
  map(imap+6 )=icell(ix-1,iy-1,iz  )
  map(imap+7 )=icell(ix  ,iy-1,iz  )
  map(imap+8 )=icell(ix+1,iy-1,iz  )

  map(imap+9 )=icell(ix+1,iy  ,iz+1)
  map(imap+10)=icell(ix+1,iy+1,iz+1)
  map(imap+11)=icell(ix  ,iy+1,iz+1)
  map(imap+12)=icell(ix-1,iy+1,iz+1)
  map(imap+13)=icell(ix-1,iy  ,iz+1)
  map(imap+14)=icell(ix-1,iy-1,iz+1)
  map(imap+15)=icell(ix  ,iy-1,iz+1)
  map(imap+16)=icell(ix+1,iy-1,iz+1)
  map(imap+17)=icell(ix  ,iy  ,iz+1)

  map(imap+18)=icell(ix+1,iy  ,iz-1)
  map(imap+19)=icell(ix+1,iy+1,iz-1)
  map(imap+20)=icell(ix  ,iy+1,iz-1)
  map(imap+21)=icell(ix-1,iy+1,iz-1)
  map(imap+22)=icell(ix-1,iy  ,iz-1)
  map(imap+23)=icell(ix-1,iy-1,iz-1)
  map(imap+24)=icell(ix  ,iy-1,iz-1)
  map(imap+25)=icell(ix+1,iy-1,iz-1)
  map(imap+26)=icell(ix  ,iy  ,iz-1)
end do
  end do
end do
```

Do I need to just find half of the **nearest neighbor** or all of them?

Comment: Please explain the problem in detail. How should the output look like? How it does look like in your case? Describe what your code does too.

Comment: I dont understand the question. I just need to consider interaction of each particle with its nearest neighbors.

Comment: Explain the code and what it should do. What is a particle in your code? What it does? What is `map`? What is `icell`?

Comment: The book of Allen and Tildesley "Computer Simulation of Liquids" contains the code for building 3D linked cell list. It uses a symmetric LJ potential and therefore only 13 from the 26 neighbouring cells. The code is to be found on [fiche 20](http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/SOURCES/FORTRAN/allen-tildesley-book/f.20.shtml). I guess your code is more or less copied from there given the similarly named variables and the statement function `icell`. Btw, using statement functions is considered bad when it comes to newer Fortran versions.

Comment: The book of Allen and Tildesley write some codes but it is is just compatible for md simulation and I need to modify this for MC simulation.

Comment: do you have a fortran programming question?  If you need help understanding the algorithm there are more appropriate forums